# Rename a github repo temporarily?

Tags: github

I found the steps to rename a github repository. My question is whether I could rename it and then change the name back to the original name. I read that github will do some redirects, so I was concerned before doing it that it would not allow me to rename it back to its original name.

Here is my scenario: I'm have a course that has an associated github repository. People are currently watching the course and need access to the github repository with the current name.

I am working on an update to the course which has a slightly revised name and hence I want to rename the github repo. For today, I want a screen shot of the newly named repo. But I can't officially (and permanently) change the name until the updated course is done and ready to go live.

Comment: Why don't you make those changes in a branch instead? Or create a fork with the new name? Or, if you literally just want to change the text for the screenshot, edit it from your browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GitHub will not block you from changing the name of the repository back to what it was previously if you have to temporarily change it like this.

I just tested it myself, was able to rename my repo right back to how it was previously.

Comment: What about changing to a different name not the name used before ?
Did you find why they are blocking the previously used name?